# What do you mean by the initial letter on javascript variables/functions

Tags: javascript, function, datatable, tabletools

The code below is just an example, this code is from jQuery DataTable.
I just would like to know what is the meaning of "o" in oTable, "b" in bServerSide and the others. Are they holding some kind of meaning?

```
  var oTable = $('#unis').dataTable({
    //"bProcessing": true,
    "bServerSide": true,
    "sAjaxSource": "index.php?...&<?php echo JSession::getFormToken() . '=1' ?>",
    "sDom": "<'row-fluid'<'span6'T><'span6'f>r>t<'row-fluid'<'span6'l><'span6'p>>",
    "sPaginationType": "bootstrap",
       "aoColumns":[
                {"bSortable": false},
                {"bSortable": false},
                {"bSortable": true},
                {"bSortable": true},
                {"bSortable": false},
              ],
    "oTableTools": {
    "aButtons": [ "delete selected", "export" ]
}  

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those prefixes refer to the datatype of the variable:

```
b = boolean
s = string
o = object
a = array
ao = array of objects
```

Answer (score 1):

Look like [Systems Hungarian notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation):

> In Systems Hungarian notation, the prefix encodes the actual data type of the variable.

```
bServerSide -> b -> bool  
sAjaxSource -> s -> string  
oTableTools -> o -> object  
aButtons    -> a -> array
```

Comment: I am a fan of the Systems Hungarian notation, prefixing to me implies the intent of the variable in a dynamic language like JS and makes debuging and reading code easier.